# Converting floats and integers to char*

Tags: c, embedded

I'm new to C and was kind of thrust into this world of embedded processing with C. I need to convert to `char*` and output integers and floating point numbers (only 0.01 resolution) to an LCD screen with an 8 bit interface. I've been reading through some of the posts and I see all these great ideas for converting `int` and `float` to `char*` but I'm not exactly sure what's going on in them.

Can someone provide a method for my two queries and a little explanation?

Comment: What specifically don't you understand in the questions you've seen so far? What did you try? Where are you stuck?

Comment: embedded can pose problems... and it sounds like you're working on a driver as well. Are you in Linux? Working on the kernel? Do you have access to the stdlibs?

Comment: If you have to write the driver as well, the difficulties of generating displayable characters from ints, floats will pale into insignificance.

Answer (score 4):

It actually depends upon the standard library, and in some embedded systems that library is partially implemented, or even absent. With a fully [standard C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) implementation you might do something like

```
char buf[40];
int i;
double x;
// compute i & x, then make a string from them with::
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "i=%2d x=%.2f", i, x);
```

Then you might send that `buf` to your LCD port, or `strdup` it for later usage. (If you use `strdup` you'll need to `free` the result).

Read the documentation of [snprintf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) for details. You probably should test the return `int` value of `snprintf`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're working on embedded programming you skould be aware of the fact that standard conversions often make use of divisions which are very taxing on any processor.

Since integers are converted using divide-by-ten you could instead implement a division using multiplication by invariant integers. This method should allow you to convert most values in the time it takes to convert a single digit in a value using division.

For floating point use the following steps:

1. save the sign and take the absolute value if sign is negative
2. multiply by 10.0 raised to the number of decimals you need
3. add 0.5 and convert to an integer
4. convert the integer to a string using the division method previously suggested
5. make sure the string is at least number of decimals + 1, insert ascii 0 at beginning as necessary
6. insert a minus sign at the beginning as required
7. insert a decimal point at the appropriate position

Here is an example that requires two decimals

```
3758.3125
375831.25    (multiply by 10^2)
375831.75    (add 0.5)
375831       (convert to integer)
"375831"     (convert to string)
"3758.31"    (insert decimal point => final result)
```

A somewhat more difficult case

```
-0.0625
0.0625       (keep sign)
6.25         (multiply by 10^2)
6.75         (add 0.5)
6            (convert to integer)
"6"          (convert to string)
"006         (insert ascii 0 as required)
"-006"       (insert minus sign)
"-0.06"      (insert decimal point => final result)
```

Comment: Ok, that clears things up a bit, thanks. Not so worried about cycle time on this, it runs in the background reading registers and outputting their values to a screen. The question also was, what is the appropriate way to convert an integer to a string? Didvide by 1000, 100, 10, 1, 0.1 etc? or add 0x30 and use "char(i)X" ?

Comment: You should always be worried about cycle times in embedded systems, if for no other reason than to keep an appropriate "embedded mindset." Adding '0'/0x30 works fine. If you use divide-by-100 (modulo 100) you can set up a vector looking like this: two_digits[100][2] = {{'0','0'},{'0','1'}, ...{'9','9'}}; Then you can halve the number of divisions required.

Comment: I assume you are referring to the one or two-digit cases. For one digit you'd use "string[i++] = '0'+value%10;value /= 10;" For two digits you'd use "j = value%100;string[i] = two_digits[j][0];string[i+1] = two_digits[j][1];i += 2;value /= 100;" The first case requires as many costly division operations per byte ascii data produced as the second does for every two bytes. The cost is incurred in that you need an array of 100*2 bytes. By BCD-encoding it you only need 100 bytes.

Comment: Basicaly I'm taking an ADC converted reading of no more than 600V, converting it to floating point, doing some math, then outputting the value to an 8 bit bus LCD. So the number will be in floating point format. the integer part, I've figured out.