# Rounding to 2 decimal points

Tags: c++, double, decimal

I've used the following to round my values to 2 decimal points:

```
 x = floor(num*100+0.5)/100;
```

and this seems to work fine; except for values like "16.60", which is "16.6".

I want to output this value like "16.60".

The way I'm outputting values is the following:

```
cout setw(12) << round(payment);
```

I've tried the following:

```
cout setw(12) << setprecision(2) << round(payment);
```

But that gave me answers like

```
1.2e+02
```

How can I output the values correctly?

Comment: There's no need to do the rounding yourself unless you need it rounded for your own purposes. Whatever you use to set the number of digits should do rounding on the output.

Comment: I wrote on this subject recently. [Check it out!][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13090868/converting-floats-and-integers-to-char/13092103#13092103

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is because `std::setprecision` doesn't set the digits after the decimal point but the significant digits if you don't change the floating point format to use a fixed number of digits after the decimal point. To change the format, you have to put [std::fixed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) into your output stream:

```
double a = 16.6;
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << a << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 11):

you can use printf / sprintf or other similar functions. Following code will format floating point value into two digits after decimals. Refer to the printf manual for more formatting info

```
float f = 1.234567
printf("%.2f\n", f);
```

Comment: Just because it's an unpopular answer doesn't mean it's wrong.

Comment: If you are allergic to printf and friends there is the type safe C++ version in `#include <boost/format.hpp>` which you can use to do: `float f = 1.234567; cout << boost::format("%.2f", f) << endl;`

Answer (score 3):

From Trevor Boyd Smith's comment:

> If you are allergic to printf and friends there is the type safe C++ version in `#include <boost/format.hpp>` which you can use to do:

```
float f = 1.234567;
cout << boost::format("%.2f") % f << endl;
```